# Pass query string parameter to SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-2012, parameter-passing, reportviewer, ssrs-2012

I have made a report in SSRS (SQL Server 2012) that takes one parameter called "STUDENT_ID". This report is deployed on report server and is working fine. My report URL is something like:

```
http://myserver/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fExportReport%2fStudentReport
```

So when I open the above URL in browser, it asks for STUDENT_ID, which I enter and press "View Report" and report is displayed. Is there are way to pass STUDENT_ID parameter directly to report rather than it first asking? For e.g. something like below:

```
http://myserver/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2fExportReport%2fStudentReport&STUDENT_ID=5
```

I tried but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you clarify `it doesn't work`? Is the report showing with `STUDENT_ID` parameter but you still need to press `View Report` or is the report not showing up at all when you use the `STUDENT_ID` parameter?

Comment: Ok I got it that to make it work like this I need to use a different URL which is http://<your server>/ReportServer?/<folder>/<reportname>&STUDENT_ID=5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the following URL worked.

```
http://<your server>/ReportServer?/<folder>/<reportname>&STUDENT_ID=5
```

Comment: http://<your server>/ReportServer/ throws a 404 for me. Is there an option we need to enable on the server?

Comment: Did you also write folder name and complete report name at the end?

Comment: Thanks Frank. I did, with and without URL encoding as the folder path contains slashes and the report name contains white space.

Comment: @RichardD So is it fixed?

Comment: Sadly not. 404 every time. The "ReportServer" routing must not be installed/configured on our install of SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

In the SSRS 20216 Report Manager, I had to set the parameter in my report (e.g., p0453_RefNo) to hidden.  Afterwards, I was able to pass values to the RDL via URL.  The name of the RDL file is rpt045_EP6_Complaints.  There was no need to include the .rdl file extension.  Parameter name is case sensitive.  For example:

http://redacted/Reports/report/redacted/rpt045_EP6_Complaints?p0453_RefNo=0612400